# Django User model validators

Tags: python, django, validation

Can anyone suggest a clever way to add validators to the Django User model?  I create files and directories based on first_name, last_name, and username, so I'd like to carefully control what characters are allowed in there using the same standard validators I have on other models.  I can't see an easy way to do this.

TIA

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really you should be subclassing the `User` object and adding validators the `correct` way, but if you like to live dangerously you could try monkey patching the User class as well.

You might put this in your app's `__init__.py` file...

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def validate_for_fs(value): # <-- If the value string doesn't meet a condition required to be a name on the filesystem then throw a ValidationError
    if foo_condition_not_met:
        raise ValidationError(u'foo is not true for %s' % value)
    if bar_condition_not_met:
        raise ValidationError(u'bar is not true for %s' % value)

for field in [f for f in User._meta.fields if f.name in ['first_name','last_name','email']]:
    field.validators.append(validate_for_fs)
```

Comment: I can't see a good way to subclass User, since it seems the native User object is pretty well built-in to Django.  I've taken the strategy you suggested here and applied it.  It works pretty well.  Thanks.  Ian